# Excel (/ Google Spreadsheets) Don't change reference when cutting -other- cells

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet cell `A1` with the formula `=SUM($P$1:$P$6)`.
Now when I cut the cells `P1:P6` and paste them to, say, `C1:C6`, it changes the formula inside `A1` to `=SUM($C$1:$C$6)`.

Any way to keep the original reference in `A1` when cutting other cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to keep the reference from updating is to not reference it directly. I.E. `=SUM(INDIRECT("P1:P6"))`

Now if for some reason you wanted to be able to copy that down your column, you'd write it something like: `=SUM(INDIRECT("P" &ROW() &":P" &ROW() + 5))`

Now if you wanted to copy that across your rows as well, you'd have to write it something like: `=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()+15) & ":" &ADDRESS(ROW()+5,COLUMN()+15)))`

Here's a reference for [using INDIRECT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213933)

Comment: that's awesome, you are a life saver!